# Sum of combinations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was calculating $\large\sum_{i=0}^{50} \binom{100}{2i}$. Although I know the approximate value of the solution, I do not know how to express it in a simpler form. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hint:  you know (or should know) $\sum \binom {100}i$.  Can you compute $\sum (-1)^i\binom {100}i$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051489/prove-that-sum-k-049-1k-binom992k-249   OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183307/to-find-the-sum-frac-1n-sum-binom-n23r-x1r/3183321#3183321

Answer (score 3):

If you know that,
$$(1-x)^n=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}x+\cdots +\binom{n}{n}x^n$$
Replace $x$ with 1,

$$\large\sum_{i=0}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i}=\large\sum_{i=1}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i-1}$$

Further, 
$$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\cdots +\binom{n}{n}x^n$$
Replace $x$ with 1,
$$2^n=\large\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}$$
$$2^n=2*\large\sum_{i=0}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i}=2*\large\sum_{i=1}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i-1}$$
$$\large\sum_{i=0}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i}=2^{n-1}$$